# How to replace emoji char to specific string from UITextView.text

Tags: ios, emoji

A string from textview.text and may have emoji, then i want to replace emoji to some string like [smile] and send to server for save. I already have a map for text and emoji.

```
self.emoji =
    @{
      @"[pretty]"   : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C%C", 0xD83D, 0xDE0A],
      @"[smile]"   : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C%C", 0xD83D, 0xDE03],
      @"[angry]"   : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C%C", 0xD83D, 0xDE20]
    }
```

This map use for display emoji and text in uilabel that string get from server. Now, how could i convert string from textview.text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your server support unicode, why don't you use emojis directly in your `NSString`?

```
NSString *emojiString = @"This is a cat ";
```

- oops, StackOverflow doesn't support unicode!